# Choose a leader when copying the Courtesan's Guild with Olympia (B)?

Tags: 7-wonders, 7-wonders-leaders

*7 Wonders* with *Leaders* extension

### Situation

1. Alice has the wonder **Olympia (B)** and builds her 3rd wonder stage (= at the end of the game she can copy a guild card of one of her neighbours).
2. Bob plays the **Courtesan's Guild** and places the *Courtesan* token at a leader card of his neighbour Carol.
3. At the end of the game, Alice copies Bob's *Courtesan's Guild*.

### What to do?

**{Variant 1}**: Alice gets another (virtual) *Courtesan* token and has to choose a leader card of one of her neighbours herself.

**{Variant 2}**: The leader card chosen by Bob is "imprinted" in the *Courtesan's Guild* and therefor Alice copies this leader card by copying the guild. (However, the points for this leader card are calculated as if she would have played it herself)

Or something else?

#### Follow-up questions if {Variant 2} would be correct

Let's say Bob would have placed the *Courtesan* token at a leader card of Alice instead of Carol. Would Alice get points (if any) for this leader card two times?

Let's say there weren't any other leader cards in play when Bob built the *Courtesan's Guild*, so he could not use the *Courtesan* token. Can Alice *now* use the token at the end of the game?

---

### Discussion elsewhere

- [boardgamegeek.com: **Olympia vs. Courtesans' guild**](http://boardgamegeek.com/thread/814632/olympia-vs-courtesans-guild)
- [boardgamegeek.com: **Olympia (B) stage 3 copying Courtesan's Guild?**](http://boardgamegeek.com/thread/651410/olympia-b-stage-3-copying-courtesans-guild)
- [boardgamegeek.com: **Courtesan's Guild (And yes, Olympia B)**](http://boardgamegeek.com/thread/832731/courtesans-guild-and-yes-olympia-b)

Comment: Other questions about Courtesan's Guild: [Abu Simbel and Courtesan's Guild](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/23545/3532) · [Timing of Roma (B)/Catan (B) and Courtesan's Guild?](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/10921/3532)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On boardgamegeek.com, Jacek Deimer says he has [asked Antoine Bauza](http://boardgamegeek.com/article/10016304#10016304), the author of the game:

> Can I chose new leader for the copy or am I forced to copy leader that already has Courteasan Token on it?
>   For example: I copy CG that copies PLATO, will I have to copy PLATO again or can I copy different leader?

Antoine's answer:

> You can copy any Leader from your two neibhourgs

So, **{Variant 1}** would be correct.

(note however: there is no source to verify that statement)

---

Here is a [statement by a Éric Franklin](http://boardgamegeek.com/article/9748584#9748584) (credited for "Revision" in the rule book) confirming that the interpretation described in {Variant 1} is correct.

---

*Update (2013-02-18):* Repos Production published an [official FAQ](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/a/10939/3532), containing this question:

> **Q:** With stage 3 of Olympia’s B side, I copy the Guild of Courtesans. Do I then need to copy the effect of the Leader where the Courtesan token is, or do I get my own virtual Courtesan token which I can use as I want?
>
> **A:** You get your own virtual courtesan token.