# Timing of Roma (B)/Catan (B) and Courtesan's Guild?

Tags: 7-wonders, 7-wonders-leaders

*7 Wonders* with *Leaders* extension (and optionally *Catan* wonder)

In the same turn (Alice and Bob are neighbours):

- Alice builds the **Courtesan's Guild**

  - → she can copy a leader
- Bob builds 2nd or 3rd **Roma (B)** stage (or 1st **Catan (B)** stage)

  - → he can recruit a leader

Can Alice place the *Courtesan* token on the leader card which Bob recruits in the same turn?

Comment: Other questions about Courtesan's Guild: [Abu Simbel and Courtesan's Guild](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/23545/3532) · [Choose a leader when copying the Courtesan's Guild with Olympia (B)?](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/10919/3532)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On boardgamegeek.com, Jacek Deimer says he has [asked Antoine Bauza](http://boardgamegeek.com/article/9994649#9994649) (the game author):

> If Courtesan Guild is built in the same turn that ROMA/CATAN recruits extra leader, can it copy leader recruited during the same turn?

Antoine answered:

> No

So Alice has to choose a leader card to copy (guild card effect) **before** Bob recruits his leader (wonder effect).