# Abu Simbel and Courtesan's Guild

Tags: 7-wonders, 7-wonders-leaders

So, this item came up last night while we were playing. I'll give you our answer, but I want to see what everyone else's thoughts are.

One player was playing as Abu Simbel, and their neighbor had the Courtesan's Guild in hand. They asked whether they could "use" an "Entombed" Leader, or what would happen if they used a Leader that was later "Entombed." We decided that they couldn't use one that had already been entombed, but if they used one that was later entombed, they would not lose the benefits.

Does this seem appropriate, or should we have gone a different route?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Courtesan token stays on a Leader that gets entombed. This is based on [Eddie the Cranky Gamer’s post on BoardGameGeek](http://www.boardgamegeek.com/article/12355980#12355980) ([to which @Jean-Sébastien links to in his answer, too](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/a/23617/3532)), who says the he’s asked Repos:

> I put the question to Repos and the answer was that the Courtesan stays in play, with the same assumed power of the now-entombed leader.

Putting the Courtesan token on an already entombed Leader is not possible. At least that’s how I understand [Ovidiu Cirlugea’s BoardGameGeek post, quoting the game author Antoine Bauza](https://boardgamegeek.com/article/14351243#14351243):

> You cannot copy it once its buried […]

Putting the Courtesan token on a Leader which is entombed on the same turn is possible, as detailed in that same BGG thread:

> Yes, you can copy a leader, even if your neighbor choose to bury it during the same turn. The copy remains, even if the original is buried after !

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](http://www.boardgamegeek.com/article/12355980#12355980), you keep the power of the entombed leader. As for seducing an already emtombed leader, I have not found anything, but I would not allow it.

Comment: Please provide the information from the link in your answer as it helps in case the link ever breaks.